# Random replacement of certain words in a file using a dictionary of replacements

Tags: python, file, dictionary, random, cpu-word

Does anybody know how to modify this script so that it randomly changes the words when it finds them.

i.e not every instance of "Bear" becomes "Snake"

```
    # A program to read a file and replace words

    word_replacement = {'Bear':'Snake', 'John':'Karen', 'Bird':'Owl'}

    with open("main.txt") as main:
        words = main.read().split()

    replaced = []
    for y in words:
        replacement = word_replacement.get(y, y)
        replaced.append(replacement)
    text = ' '.join(replaced)


    print (text)

    new_main = open("main.txt", 'w')
    new_main.write(text)
    new_main.close()
```

Comment: Do you have a list of replacement words to choose from at random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to *randomly* decide to apply the replacement:

```
import random
replacement = word_replacement.get(y, y) if random.random() > 0.5 else y
```

In the example above it will change `"Bear"` to `"Snake"` (or any other words in word_replacement) with a ~0.5 probability. You can change the value to your desire *randomness*.

Putting all together:

```
# A program to read a file and replace words
import random

word_replacement = {'Bear': 'Snake', 'John': 'Karen', 'Bird': 'Owl'}

with open("main.txt") as main:
    words = main.read().split()

    replaced = []
    for y in words:
        replacement = word_replacement.get(y, y) if random.random() > 0.5 else y
        replaced.append(replacement)
    text = ' '.join(replaced)
    print(text)

with open("main.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(text)
```

**Output** *(for Bear Bear Bear as main.txt)*

```
Snake Bear Bear
```